# Colors in OpenGL VBOs?

Tags: opengl, vbo

I'm trying to add colors to my object that using a single struct and single VBO in OpenGL.  To do this, I have a `Vertex` struct that I created that looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
    float a;
} Vertex;
```

I already know that I'm setting all of the coordinates and colors correctly to get what I want, because I ran a test iterating over each object I have stored in my list and drawing out the points and setting the colors using `glVertex3f` and `glColor4f` (this was significantly slower than what I'm looking for).  But when I try to draw it using VBOs I just get a huge mess of colored triangles going everywhere.

The part of my rendering loop that draws the VBO looks like this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, offsetof(Vertex, r), NULL);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertex_amount);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);
                             ^
```

The position values in an array of `Vertex`s are not tightly packed so you can't use `0` for `stride`.  Use `sizeof( Vertex )`.

```
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, offsetof(Vertex, r), NULL);
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm...not sure what you're going for here.  Perhaps you thought the 3rd parameter of [`glVertexPointer()`/`glColorPointer()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) was `pointer` instead of `stride`?  Move your `offsetof()` to the final parameter, `pointer`.

All together:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof( Vertex ), offsetof(Vertex, x) );
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof( Vertex ), offsetof(Vertex, r) );
```

You may have to cast the `pointer` parameter values to `void*` depending on how you've implemented `offsetof()`.